# Translation in Magento from a single file

Tags: php, magento, csv, translation, magento-1.7

Is it possible to have a single CSV file to make all the translation ? Similar to as we can do all xml changes from a single file local.xml

I downloaded a Swedish translation package and tried to translate some words which are not yet been translated. I saw the csv files are named similar to the xml layout files. So was curious to know if there is any possibility to have similar functionality with translation ?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a file **translate.csv** inside the folder `app/design/your_theme/locale/_localecode_/` and you can enter the translation text there.
Check out this [link](http://blog.belvg.com/magento-certified-developer-exam-internationalization.html) for more details

Comment: You're right, only it need to be placed in app/design/your_package/your_theme/locale/_localecode_/

Comment: That means I have to put that translation file for every design that I want to use in my stores, in case I am using multiple stores with multiple design.

Comment: Yes exactly.You need to copy the folder to each themes you are using in your store.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of Magento core helpers. I use sales helper in my admin custom module, it works for me now. Important thing is we want to set locale in our custom module as well.

```
if ($order->getStoreId()) {
                Mage::app()->getLocale()->emulate($order->getStoreId());
                Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($order->getStoreId());
            }

$page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Packing Note'), 30, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
```

I added translation file to default translation files(Mage_sales.csv) for all locale. It's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

CSV files are organised as modules in magento locale. But you can place the text you need to translate in any CSV file as you wish. It will work. But note that, it should be under that particular language's folder, to which you need to translate.

For an example assume you have a module `first_module.csv`. You can place any text you need to translate in this file. No matter even the text is from any other modules. The translation will work **if this module is enabled**.

**As far as I know,** By organizing CSVs by modules, you can control the translation of text, according to various modules. But if not, you wont have any such module vise control over translation.

Comment: If I add any new csv file, let's say new.csv to the list under sv_SE folder then will that translation work ?

Comment: No. CSV file's name should be `YourPackage_YourModule.csv` format and you should say it in `config.xml`. Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044584/how-does-magento-translate-works