# Magento Translations in template files

Tags: php, magento, translation

I'm working on the footer template of a Magento app for a site that will be available in several languages.

I'm concerned how translations will work if I use simple mark up.  For instance:

```
<span>Payment Accepted</span>
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/visa-logo.png');?>" alt="visa logo"/>
```

I've seen `<?php echo $this->__('Some Text'); ?>` quite often throughout the Magento template files, is this used for translations? If it is how does it work?

The `<?php echo $this->__('Some Text'); ?>` is often wrapped within a `<span class="label">` tag too.

Alternatively, would I be better using a static block & effecting the translation change on the admin panel, with the different store views available for static blocks?

Answer (score 0):

You are right. `<?php echo $this->__('Some Text'); ?>` is used for translations. The translate method grabs the translation from the appropriate module csv file or from the theme's translate.csv or the database (inline translation).

A good overview can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10047702/3670130