# Magento $this->__('Create an Account')

Tags: magento

In Magento $this->__('Create an Account') How this echo Create an Account?

```
abstract class Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{ public function __()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    $expr = new Mage_Core_Model_Translate_Expr(array_shift($args), $this->_getModuleName());
    array_unshift($args, $expr);
    return Mage::app()->getTranslator()->translate($args);
}
```

I saw that  __ function in Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract Class.but i cant understand Mage::app()->getTranslator()->translate($args) what's happending in that getTranslator function.

```
public function getTranslator()
{
    if (!$this->_translator) {
        $this->_translator = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
    }
    return $this->_translator;
}
```

Mage::getSingleton('core/translate') what's happening there ? and why in this function call like core/translate which file its denote and how it Create an Account text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might search how the magento translator works

What ever text is written in $this->_('') will dynamically translated to the current locale which is loaded in your current store(That text must be specified in magento-root/app/locale//.csv)

I think the below answer might be helpfull

[How does Magento translate works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044584/how-does-magento-translate-works/10047702#10047702)